# Raspberry apache server not showing images and the site is acting weird

Tags: pi-3, server, apache-httpd

I'm hosting a site made with codeigniter in a raspberry 3 with Apache which is basically a form and the pictures aren't showing.

I see the files are with user and group www-data and I'm trying to have the raspi host several sites so I'm not sure if it's something with permissions or some miss configuration  in the host file or something the weird part is that when I access the site within the raspberry and enter the site by the domain, the images only load when I access the image directly, but not on site itself

I've also checked the log at the var/log/Apache2/ and nothing appears to show an error log.

Also when you enter the site it enters like if it's already submiting a $_POST. Because it is showing an error like all the fields are empty.

Comment: it's probably a combination of configuration error, and coding error - as you've shared neither config nor code, I can only speculate, and can only confirm your suspicions

Comment: This is a question about Apache and does not belong to Raspberry Pi.